# "Software & updates" activates Ubuntu Software on v 22.04. after reinstall of Desktop It worked partially untill I uninstalled a Freecad on this app

Tags: 22.04, software-center

Software & Updates opens Ubuntu Software on v 22.04. even after reinstalling of Desktop. It worked partially until I uninstalled Free Cad on this app.There are stil Freecad program files in the Home directory even after uninstalling.

Comment: Please ask a clear concise question.